# Error with pip install git (after switching to python 3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just changed my project's interpreter to python 3.6 and have to install git library again.

When i run the command "pip install --proxy=some_proxy git" i get the following error message:

"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement git (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for git".

Why does it happen ?

Comment: Had the same issue when I changed machines. I'd hazard a guess that it's because I had python2 on the last box but python 3.7.0 on the new one. [Antony Joseph's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7799341/antony-joseph) solution worked for me. If it works for you, you might consider marking it as the answer.

Answer (score 19):

I was getting the same error. Using

```
pip install gitpython
```

solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

The error means that there is no such package as `git`. Check the name of the package you want to install.